# In Qiskit, no state vector after measure and reset

Tags: qiskit, quantum-state

The code below doesn't work. I am looking for a workaround.
OK, I can save the state vector as numpy array, recreate the whole circuit and initialize it thanks to this array. It works, but any simpler idea would be welcome!

```
from qiskit.quantum_info import  Statevector
q=QuantumRegister(1)
c=ClassicalRegister(1)
qc=QuantumCircuit(q,c)

sv = Statevector(qc)
print(sv)

# Destroy the qubit
qc.measure(0,0) 

# Recreate the qubit
qc.reset(0)
print(qc)
sv = Statevector(qc)
print(sv) # => Error: 'Cannot apply instruction with classical bits: measure'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`save_statevector`](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.library.save_statevector.html) from Qiskit Aer as follows

```
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

simulator = AerSimulator()

# Create your circuit as usual
q=QuantumRegister(1)
c=ClassicalRegister(1)
qc=QuantumCircuit(q,c)

# Add save_statevector anywhere in the circuit to save the statevector at this point
qc.save_statevector('psi1')

qc.measure(0,0) 
qc.reset(0)

# You can add save_statevector more than once
qc.save_statevector('psi2')

# Simulate the circuit
job = simulator.run(qc)
 
# Extract statevectors from the result
psi1 = job.result().data()['psi1']
print(psi1)

psi2 = job.result().data()['psi2']
print(psi2)
```

Comment: Thank you for this quick answer. However, this is not really what I’m looking for. In addition, after qc.save_statevector('psi1') the command sv = Statevector(qc)
 generates an error.